# Update the table with where condition in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

```
update MGR.DRAFT
set qty = '330' 
where (select * 
       from MGR.DRAFT 
       where unit = '6' 
         and group = 'TT' 
         and loc = 'ciu' 
         and qty = '230.8315625')
```

This query throws an error:

> SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: remove the `( select * from mgr.draft where`, and the final `)`. You don't need a subquery here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
This error comes when you are missing some expression.

Add this code:

```
UPDATE MGR.DRAFT
SET qty = '330'
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM MGR.DRAFT
  WHERE unit = '6'
    AND group = 'TT'
    AND loc = 'ciu'
    AND qty = '230.8315625'
);
```

I hope this will work for you!!

Answer (score 2):

```
update MGR.DRAFT
set qty= '330'
where unit='6' and group='TT' and loc='ciu' and qty='230.8315625'
```